# ISO8601 DateTime Parsing when including date and timezone but no time component in Python

Tags: python, parsing, datetime

I have tried parsing a string to a Python datetime object using two different methods: iso8601.parse_date and dateutil.parser.parse.

Both of these methods return an error when trying to parse "2017-19-10Z" or "2017-19-10-0500". I would like to not write my own parser if possible. The closest thing I can get to a valid datetime using these values is "2017-19-10T00Z".

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think they are valid by ISO8601, you can't have a time zone without the time component. Where does that come from?

Comment: Dates in ISO8601 must be in year-month-day format. Your inputs seem to be in year-day-month (as `19` is not a month). And the timezone/offset designators (`Z` and `-0500`) must come after a time (hour:minute:second - although minutes and seconds are optional) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601